# (VS2022/MFC/Visual c++) Cannot add Event Handler. "Message Type" does not appear in dialog

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, visual-studio-2022

I made
appliclation type- Dialog based MFC project, named Viewer
and added `IDR_MAIN_MENU` using Add Resource dialog.

[image: added Menu named IDR_MAIN_MENU]

and have set up like this

[image: this]

[image]

[image]

and boom! there is no `Message type`
Ive taught that there should be `COMMAND` or `UPDATE_COMMAND_UI`,
but there is nothing
i have no idea what i did wrong.

one of my classmate had same problem,
and he solved this problem indirectly
-by installing VS2019

my environment is WINDOWS10/VS2022
with

```
v143 c++ build tools,
MSVC v143- VS2022 c++ x64/x86 build tools
```

installed.

[image]

sorry for the korean in installer screenshot.

Any Idea of what I did wrong?
Should I REALLY install another version of VS?

Comment: +i just had installed in VS 2019 and same project works just fine in vs2019. IDK what makes this bug in VS2022

Comment: Those wizards are broken, and have been broken for years. Time to move on and leave them behind. You'll have to write the code by hand now. Jeff Prosise' [Programming Windows with MFC](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0072850574) explains how that works.

Comment: I have tested this, the ClassWizard works in VS2022! There is an alternative way: Open the ClassWizard from them menu Project-Class Wizard.. or press CTRL+SHIFT+X, then you can add the handlers here

Answer (score 0):

Same thing here, Microsoft close my issue but it still appears in 17.4.0
In the current Preview 17.5.0 you can pick a message type but the generated code ist wrong.